# Convert DataFrame of options with 5*5 grid of choice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gridview, grid

Following are the standard values for score and grades.
Score column contains numbers within specified range.

| Score | Grade1 | Score2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <260 | A1 | <200 | D1 | ID1 |
| 260-275 | A2 | 200-250 | D2 | ID2 |
| 275-280 | A3 | 250-260 | D3 | ID3 |
| 280-285 | A4 | 260-270 | D4 | ID4 |
| >=285 | A5 | >=270 | D5 | ID5 |

Input :-

| Score | Grade1 | Score2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 290 | A1 | 265 | D3 | ID2 |

Output:-

| Tiers | Grade | Grade1 | Score2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  | ID2 |
| 3 |  |  |  | D3 |  |
| 4 |  |  | 265 |  |  |
| 5 | 290 |  |  |  |  |

Input :-

| Score | Grade1 | Score2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 290 | A1 | 265 | D3 | ID2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df` and `df_input` your two DataFrames, you can use a combination of [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
# get df_input as Series
s = df_input.loc[0]

# find identical values
mask = df.eq(s)

# match ranges
def match_range(val, ref):
    # extract the upper value, for the last replace by np.inf
    s = pd.to_numeric(ref.str.extract('[<-](\d+)', expand=False)).fillna(np.inf)
    # define default output as False
    out = np.zeros(len(ref), dtype=bool)
    # find matching position
    out[np.searchsorted(s, val)] = True
    return out

# apply match_range on columns for which a direct match failed
m = ~mask.any()
mask.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: match_range(s[x.name], x))

# generate output
out = (pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, s, ''),
                    index=np.arange(len(df))+1,
                    columns=df.columns)
         .rename_axis('Tiers').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   Tiers Score Grade1 Score2 Grade3 Grade4
0      1           A1                     
1      2                               ID2
2      3                         D3       
3      4                 265              
4      5   290
```

Used inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': ['<260', '260-275', '275-280', '280-285', '>=285'],
                   'Grade1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                   'Score2': ['<200', '200-250', '250-260', '260-270', '>=270'],
                   'Grade3': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'],
                   'Grade4': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID5']})

df_input = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [290], 'Grade1': ['A1'], 'Score2': [265], 'Grade3': ['D3'], 'Grade4': ['ID2']})
```

Comment: Can you create df and df_input to normalize more.

Comment: yes provide more information with input df's.

Comment: out = (pd.DataFrame(np.where(out, s, ''),
                    index=np.arange(len(df))+1,
                    columns=df.columns)
         .rename_axis('Tiers').reset_index()
      ) Here, right side out is not defined above which gives out is not defined error.

Comment: @Swetha it should be `mask`, I had changed the name for clarity when writing the answer and forgot this one ;) I checked and the updated code is running

Answer (score 0):

I did, maybe someone will make it shorter. Will work if df2 has one row.Difficulty in creating a range for searching. If it is possible to specify two values from and to at once, then it can be made easier.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hist = len(df1) - 1

df1['Score'] = df1['Score'].str.replace("<|>|=", "", regex=True).str.split('-')
df1['Score2'] = df1['Score2'].str.replace("<|>|=", "", regex=True).str.split('-')

df1.loc[0, ['Score', 'Score2']] = [[0, 0], [df1.loc[0, 'Score'][0], df1.loc[0, 'Score2'][0]]]
df1.loc[hist, ['Score', 'Score2']] = [[df1.loc[hist, 'Score'][0], df1.loc[hist, 'Score2'][0]], [np.inf, np.inf]]


ind = (df1['Score'].str[0].astype(float) <= df2['Score'].values[0]) & \
      (df1['Score'].str[1].astype(float) >= df2['Score'].values[0])

ind2 = (df1['Score2'].str[0].astype(float) <= df2['Score2'].values[0]) & \
      (df1['Score2'].str[1].astype(float) >= df2['Score2'].values[0])

df1 = df1[df1.eq(df2.iloc[0])]

df1.loc[df1[ind].index, 'Score'] = df2['Score'].values
df1.loc[df1[ind2].index, 'Score2'] = df2['Score2'].values

df1.insert(0, 'Tiers', range(1, hist + 2))

df1 = df1.fillna('')#if NaN values are needed instead of an empty string, comment out this line

print(df1)
```

Output

```
   Tiers Score Grade1 Score2 Grade3 Grade4
0      1           A1                     
1      2                               ID2
2      3                         D3       
3      4                 265              
4      5   290
```